# Finding a specific child div via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find and append some text in a dynamically created parent div 
but its not working.
Here is what I have tried.

```
var mainDiv = "" +
"<div>" +
    "<div></div>" +
    "<div>" +
        "<div class='image-here'></div>" +
    "</div>" +
"</div>"; // proper script is in Fiddle

var imageDiv = $(mainDiv).children(".image-here");
$(imageDiv).html("text allocated");
$(mainDiv).dialog();
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/10166/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
var imageDiv = $(mainDiv).children(".image-here");
$(imageDiv).html("text allocated");
$(mainDiv).dialog()
```

to this:

```
$(mainDiv).dialog().find(".image-here").html("text allocated");
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ur92dyzf/)

Comment: Document can have many elements having class `image-here`. `find()` seems better approach. Also note that DOM manipulations should be handled before showing `dialog()`

Comment: it will append this html to all divs with class "image-here" or just for the div shown in dialog ?

Comment: The above code will append to all if there are more, but should be possible to make it more specific :)

Comment: actually I want to append this text only to the div in mainDiv, as there are multiple dialog containing child divs with class image-here, thats why i was trying to find this div within the mainDiv.

Comment: Just use `find` instead of `children`..Simple enough ?

Comment: I just updated the code and link to JSFiddle, this should add the text only to the created dialog :)